# I am using YoxView and want a pdf file to open in full screen not sure how to do this

Tags: portfolio, yoxview

I am using this code:

```
<a href='#pdf_test'>
    <img src="pdf_thumbnail.jpg" alt="PDF" />
</a>

<div id="pdf_test" title="Document's name" style='display:none; width: 850px; height:     1100px;'>
    <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
        <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
    </object>
</div>
```

How do I get the PDF to open in full screen? www.nicholashopp.com/portfolio it is the 4th square.

Answer (score 0):

I think that my answer is too late, but you should to set `allowInternalLinks` as `true`

```
try:
$(".yoxview").yoxview({
      allowInternalLinks:true
});
```

See: 
http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/usage.aspx#options
item:**Inline elements and other media types**

Good Luck
Dan